# ASP.Net - Checking User Details From Business Layer

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm using asp.net configuration manager and the standard login control to allow users to logon.

Can I find what user is currently logged in from the business layer or do I need to pass it in from the UI?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

//OR you may put user into session and access it like this

HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]
```